# Circle areas on squared grid

Tags: geometry, circles, area

There is a circle. On 9 equal squares. Every square has some value assigned to it. Every square gets weight, depending of what percentage of it is circle (area-wise). I need to find circle radius, such that sum(weight of square * value of square) = some Y.
We know circle center (which is inside the middle square), values of squares and height (width) of square. Circle borders can't exceed these 9 squares.

I need some universal formula so I could implement it using SQL syntax.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Have you tried this with a square instead of a circle? That is probably easier to think about and give you insight into the syntax issues.

Comment: To achieve my goal i need circle

Comment: There isn't going to be some simple universal formula, and to further require it in SQL will be horrendous. Maybe if you know the 9 numbers are always consistent with an actual solution, there might be a simple(r) answer. The problem is also ill-posed since there generally won't (numerically) be a unique solution.

Comment: Victor is spot-on. This is the sort of problem I'd solve only for paid consulting money, because it's messy and yet not likely to be interesting. One small idea: if you draw axes through the center of the circle, you divide the middle column into two columns, and the same for the middle row, so you now have a 4x4 grid of not-quite-squares, but ones that'll make your integrations nicer. 2nd small idea: you can probably do an inclusion-exclusion trick to alter the square-values so that all integrals are either half-space or quadrant integrals, making the thing a bit more reasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the weights of your squares are fixed. Your sum turn into a weight sum of the area of intersection of your circle with each of the squares.

The intersection area between a circle and a square can further breakdown and expressed in terms of the area of intersection between a circle with four quadrants. i.e. those set of the form 
$$(-\infty, u] \times (-\infty,v ] = \big\{\; (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \le u, y \le v \;\big\}$$

Let $C$ be your circle. For any $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, let

$$\Delta_C(u,v) = \text{Area}(\;C \cap (-\infty,u] \times (-\infty,v]\;)$$

For any rectangle $[a_1, a_2] \times [b_1,b_2]$, we have following identity:

$$\text{Area}( C \cap [a_1, a_2] \times [b_1, b_2 ] ) = 
\Delta_C( a_1, b_1 ) - \Delta_C( a_1, b_2 ) - \Delta_C( a_2, b_1 ) + \Delta_C( a_2, b_2 )$$

Assume your circle is centered at $(p,q)$ with radius $r$ and $C_0$ is the unit circle, By translation symmetry and scaling argument, we have
$$\Delta_C(a, b)  = r^2 \Delta_{C_0}\left(\frac{a-p}{r},\frac{b-q}{r}\right)$$

At the end, we just need to figure out what $\Delta_{C_0}( x, y )$ are. For simplicity of presentation, we will drop the $C_0$ subscript from $\Delta_{C_0}$ from now on.

For any $u \in \mathbb{R}$, let $h(u)$ be the area of intersection between the unit disk $C_0$ with the half plane $(-\infty, u)\times(-\infty,\infty)$. It is not hard to work
out

$$h(u) = \Delta(u,\infty) = \begin{cases}
\pi,& u \in [1,\infty)\\
\pi - \cos^{-1}(u) + u\sqrt{1-u^2},& u \in (-1,1)\\
0,& u \in (-\infty, -1]
\end{cases}$$

To determine the value of $\Delta(u,v)$, one can use following table.

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
\hline
 \verb/Condition/ && \Delta(u,v)\\
\hline
u^2 + v^2 \le 1 && \frac{h(u) + h(v)}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} + uv\\
u \le -1 \vee v \le -1 && 0\\
u \ge  1 \wedge v \ge 1 && \pi\\
u \ge  1 && h(v)\\
v \ge  1 && h(u)\\
u \ge  0 \wedge v \ge 0 && h(u) + h(v) - \pi\\
u \ge  0 \wedge v \le 0 && h(v)\\
u \le  0 \wedge v \ge 0 && h(u)\\
\verb/otherwise/ && 0\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

One look at the conditions in this table one by one. 
If $(u,v)$ satisfy a condition, then $\Delta(u,v)$ will be given by the expression at the right. If not, move to next condition.

Finally, here is a picture illustrating in which range, one should use which formula for $\Delta(u,v)$.

[image: Ranges of $\Delta(x,y)$]

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose your intersections into [circular segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment), triangles and rectangles. The exact arrangement of these different shapes depends on where the circle intersects which side of each square. So you'll need a lot of case distinctions. There is nothing really complicated about this, but nevertheless an ugly and boring amount of work. That's the reason I don't go into more detail here.