# Area of Circle Overlapped by Rectangle

Tags: geometry, circles, area, percentages, rectangles

I'm trying to determine 'how much' (as a percentage) a 2D rectangle fills a 2D circle.

**Actual Application:**

I was comparing the accuracy of some computer game weapons by calculating the max possible dispersion from the weapon's shell origion at a given range. After that, I added a player stand in to help visualize the possible dispersion vs size of the target. Of course I can eyeball the values, but I don't know how to calculate this geometry (as the player's head and feet would not actually be inside the dispersion area, so a basic area calculation is not accurate).

Any guidance is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I'm sorry that the question was not more clear, I'll try to elaborate:

In the case of the smaller circle, if you did a basic area calculation of the circle (1.828) and the rectangle (1.6), the result would say that the rectangle fills ~87% of the circle. However, the person cannot be compacted, and their upper body and lower body do not fall within the circle, and therefore the result is not accurate.

Now I think all I need to do is to subtract the difference of the circle's diameter from the max extents of the rectangle (so 2m - 1.526 = 0.474, or in other words, just make the rectangle as tall as the circle's diameter) making the rectangle's new area 1.526 * 0.8. Making the new percentage ~69%, which should be much more accurate. Am I on the right track?

Image:

[image]

**Actual Values from the Test:**

Player: 2m tall, 0.8m wide.

Weapon Dispersion Circle A (green): radius = 0.763.

Weapon Dispersion Circle B (red): radius = 1.05.

Comment: If the rectangle falls entirely inside the circle, then the answer may be found by taking a ratio of the rectangle's area to the circle's area.  Othewise some specifics of how the rectangle overlaps the circle are needed.

Comment: It is one the right track, the correct ratio should be around $\frac{1.1623128}{\pi (0.763)^2} \approx 63.55\%$. However, instead of setting the height of the rectangle as the diameter $d = 1.526$ of circle, I will set it to a number between $d$ and the side length of the intersection $\ell = 2 \sqrt{0.763^2 - 0.4^2} \approx 1.29949$. Let's say we approximate the height of the rectangle as $\frac{2d+\ell}{3} \approx 1.45050$, the ratio becomes $\frac{1.45050\times 0.8}{\pi (0.763)^2} \approx 63.45\%$. Accurate to within $1%$ of the correct value.

Comment: @achille hui: Very interesting. If you don't mind, I do have some followup questions: 1) Why did you decide to use (2d+L)/3 to find the ratio? 2) You mentioned the correct ratio 'should be around a number' and that your estimate was close to the "correct value". So how did you determine what the correct value is in the first place? Did you use a more sophisticated series of steps? At any rate, thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: 1) When the width of the rectangle is not too big, one can approximate the top/bottom of the circle by a quadratic polynomial, If you compute the average height of the circle within the rectangle, you will obtain the expression $(2d+L)/3$ as the width tends to $0$. 2) The correct value is computed by the function given in my answer. It covers all the possible ways ( there are tons of them) a circle can intersect with a rectangle and give you the actual area (up to machine accuracy).

Comment: @achille hui: I see, thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: @achille hui: In case you still get updates about this thread, I've run into a situation where a smaller radius actually decreases the coverage percentage and I'm not sure how to properly calculate it [see that here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329220/calculating-the-area-of-a-circle-occupied-by-a-rectangle]. By the way, if you make your response an answer, I'll mark it correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Is the rectangle always centered to the circle?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is symmetric when the shapes are centered to each other. As such, I can see 4 cases of overlap between a circle of radius $R$ and a rectangle of half lengths $a$ and $b$.

[image: four cases]

The shaded area corresponding to one quadrant only is calculated as follows: Consider the cases where $b \leq a$ and vary the radius $R$ from small to large.

$$ \text{(Area)} = 
\begin{cases}
  \tfrac{\pi}{4} R^2 & R \leq b \\
  \tfrac{1}{2} b \sqrt{R^2-b^2} + \tfrac{1}{2} R^2 \sin^{-1}\left( \tfrac{b}{R} \right) &  
b < R \leq a \\
   \tfrac{1}{2} \left( a \sqrt{R^2-a^2} + b \sqrt{R^2-b^2} \right) + \tfrac{1}{4} R^2 \left( 2 \sin^{-1}\left( \tfrac{a}{R} \right) + 2 \sin^{-1} \left( \tfrac{b}{R} \right)- \pi \right) & a < R \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \\
 a b & R > \sqrt{a^2+b^2}
\end{cases} $$

You can check that at the transition values of $R$ the area results match between adjacent cases. For example area (2) when $R=b$ is $\tfrac{1}{2} b^2 \sin^{-1} \left( \tfrac{b}{b} \right) + \tfrac{1}{2} b \sqrt{b^2-b^2} = \tfrac{\pi}{4} b^2$ which equals the area (1) when $R=b$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a long comment to present some code to compute the numbers.

For a more human readable description about the math behind the screen, 
please consult this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/829862/59379) instead. It is pointless to repeat the description here.

---

The numerical values of the two areas are

```
1.162312801155704 // ar_area(0.763,0,0,-0.4,-1,0.4,1)
                  // ~ 72.64455% of rectangle, 63.55125% of circle

1.59553612458975  // ar_area(1.050,0,0,-0.4,-1,0.4,1)
                  // ~ 99.72101% of rectangle, 46.06575% of circle
```

Computing using an user-defined function `ar_area(r,xc,yc,x0,y0,x1,y1)`.
The `r` is the radius of the circle, `(xc,yc)` its center. The `(x0,y0)` and `(x1,y1)` specify the lower-left and upper-right corner of the rectangles.

Following are the actual code in `maxima` I used to compute these numbers. 
I think it should be obvious how to translate it to other languages.

```
ar_h(u) := if( u >= 1 ) then 
               %pi 
           else if( u > -1 ) then 
               %pi - acos(u) + u*sqrt(1-u^2) 
           else 
                0;

ar_quad(u,v) := 
    if( u^2 + v^2 <= 1) then 
        (ar_h(u)+ar_h(v))/2 - %pi/4 + u*v 
    else if( u <= -1 or v <= -1) then
        0
    else if( u >= 1 and v >= 1 ) then 
        %pi
    else if( u >= 1 )then 
        ar_h(v)
    else if( v >= 1 ) then 
        ar_h(u)
    else if( u >= 0 and v >= 0 ) then
        ar_h(u)+ar_h(v) - %pi
    else if( u >= 0 and v <= 0 ) then 
        ar_h(v)
    else if( u <= 0 and v >= 0 ) then
        ar_h(u)
    else
        0;

ar_rect(x0,y0,x1,y1) := ar_quad(x0,y0) + ar_quad(x1,y1) - ar_quad(x0,y1) - ar_quad(x1,y0);
ar_area(r,xc,yc,x0,y0,x1,y1) := r^2 * ar_rect((x0-xc)/r,(y0-yc)/r,(x1-xc)/r,(y1-yc)/r);
```