# Portion of square area within a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, area

I have a circle of center $(x_c, y_c)$ and radius $r$, and a square of center $(x_s, y_s)$ and width $w$:

[image]

The square will always be oriented such that its sides are parallel to the x,y axis of a system such as the one shown in the figure, centered at $(x_c, y_c)$.

How can I obtain the area of the square that is within the limit defined by the radius of the circle (ie: the red portion)? This portion will be 1 if the entire square is inside the radius $r$, and zero if the entire square is outside.

Comment: What orientation is the square to the circle?  The will also be a required piece of information.  Or equivalently we need one (just one) of the corners.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: Do you need an exact or approximate evaluation ?

Comment: @fleablood: assuming an axis-aligned square causes no loss of generality.

Comment: If possible, I need an exact evaluation. But I could do with an approximate one if it is substantially simpler (and not too far off).

Comment: There are tons of special case for the value. see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/829862/59379) for details.

Comment: Will do, thank you @achillehui!

Comment: You've drawn the square as very much smaller than the circle, will this always be the case?

Comment: Yes, the full square will never represent more than 1/10th of the area of the circle at the most extreme case.

Comment: "assuming an axis-aligned square causes no loss of generality"  what do you mean?  A circle centered and (0,0) with radius 1. and a square centered at (1.5, 0) with side 1 corners at (1,0.5)(1,-0.5)(2,0.5)(2,-0.5) will have a different answer than a square with corners at (1.5,$\sqrt{2}/2$)(1.5,-$\sqrt{2}/2$)(1.5- $\sqrt{2}/2$,0)(1.5+$\sqrt{2}/2$).  Sure we can fix the square to be parallel to the axis, but then you have to know the orientation of the circle.  Or we could fix the circle and square to have centers horizontal, but then we need to know the orientation of the square.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You can derive the area inside the square from the area inside an infinite "corner" ($x\ge x_c,y\ge y_c$), by summing algebraically contributions from the four vertices of the square.

The area covered by a corner is obtained by integrating $\sqrt{1-x^2}-y_c$ from $x_c$ to the solution of $\sqrt{1-x^2}-y_c=0$ (WLOG, $r=1$).

And

$$\int\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}2-\frac{\arcsin x}2.$$

You need to discuss a little further for the four quadrants.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand this answer. What is an infinite "corner"? Where are $x_s, y_s$? What do you mean buy "discuss a little further for the four quadrants"?

Comment: @Gabriel: hope the figure will make it a little clearer. A corner is formed by two perpendicular half-lines.

Comment: Sorry, still lost :(

Comment: @Gabriel: sorry, I have no more time now.

Comment: No worries I'll look into it with more detail. Thank you for your answer!